# Scientific computing in Python for MATLAB programmers

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I was wondering if anybody knows of a good tutorial or introductory text on scientific computing on Python/SciPy for MATLAB programmers.

I was thinking of something along the lines of [David Hiebeler's text](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf) on [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_programming_language) for MATLAB programmers, which provides a side-by-side reference between both languages.

To clarify, my current environment of choice is [Python(x,y)](http://www.pythonxy.com/) with [Spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/), but anything that shows how to translate some fundamental operations, built-ins and utilities between MATLAB and  SciPy + third-party extensions would be great.

Comment: I don't have references at hand, but there are indeed several tutorials on migrating to Python.  Be careful what you wish for, though, because Python is a language with multiple possible interfaces (much like R).  For instance, Python(x,y) is a pretty amazing suite that encompasses a lot of the GUI goodness of Matlab with a lot of stuff one doesn't encounter in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks @Iterator. Python(x,y) is my environment of choice, but anything on how MATLAB builtins translate into Python would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)

You didn't ask for tools, but I thought I'd mention [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/).

Comment: That's a great reference @aix. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page) is a great resource for translating between languages.  Most problems have a python example, and there are several hundred MATLAB equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a little outdated for some commands, but looks like a good reference from Numpy/Scipy to MATLAB:

http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-python-xref.pdf